# Calling a Method in another class using TestNG in Java

Tags: java, testng, appium, appium-android

I am using TestNG and Java to automate an android app.

I am having difficulty in calling a method from one class to another class.

Here is the code.

for class 1 (Appium)

```
//public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android device");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "100");
            cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "App Package");
            cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"App Activity");
            cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
            cap.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
            return driver;
        } 
}
```

I need to call the `capabilities()` method in another .java class but I am using TestNG.

so in `@Test` in the new class I need this method in the variable driver. I can't do it by extending this class to the new class. Is some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multilevel inheritance in this case. Make one class in which you will set the capabilities and extend that class from another class where you will write your @BeforeSuite and now extend this class from your test classes and @BeforeSuite will run automatically from all the test classes.

For example:

```
    class CapabilitiesClass{
    public void setCapabilities(){
         //Set your capabilities here
          }
     }

    class BaseClass extends CapabilitiesClass{
    //Write your BeforeSuite here and call the parent class method
    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp(){
        setCapabilities();
    }

    class TestClass extends BaseClass{
    //Write your @Test here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class as `DriverUtility` with the method:

```
public class DriverUtility {

   public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabilities() {
```

In you test call it as:

```
public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = DriverUtility.capabilities();
```